# Realm.io - How to use defaultPropertyValues while using response data from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I know we have to use defaultPropertyValues.
Class structure:

```
@interface Event : RLMObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *roomName;
....
- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes;

@end

@implementation Event

+ (NSDictionary *)defaultPropertyValues {
    return @{@"roomName" : @""};
}

- (instancetype)initWithAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.roomName = [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"room"];
        .......
    }
    return self;
}
```

...

```
Event *school = [[IVEvent alloc] initWithAttributes:dict];
[realm addObject:school];
```

'RLMException', reason: 'No value or default value specified for property 'roomName' in 'Event''

This is because roomName is getting assigned by defaultPropertyValues class method. But as soon as it get parsed from attributes dictionary then roomName becomes nil and getting crashed. Is there any better way to handle this ? I don't want to put if condition on [attributes valueForKeyPath:@"room"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map NSDictionaries to RLMObjects by using Realm's built-in method [`createOrUpdateInRealm:withObject:`](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/createOrUpdateInRealm:withObject:) on your entity class (`Event`)  instead of a custom initializer. This will, as documented, fall back to use the default value when no value is given:

> The object used to populate the object. This can be any key/value coding compliant object, or a JSON object such as those returned from
>   the methods in NSJSONSerialization, or an NSArray with one object for
>   each persisted property. An exception will be thrown if any required
>   properties are not present and no default is set.

Otherwise you would need to ensure in your custom initializer, that you don't overwrite properties with nil values. If you have a custom mapping, where the attribute names are not the same and your server response is in JSON format, a object-mapping library like [Realm-JSON](https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON) could be interesting for you.